# List to String with a space in between?

Tags: python, list

['a', 'b', 'c', '', 'd', 'e']
Is it possible to convert this list into a string but it remains in the format of:
'abc de' - the output should include the space in between

Comment: `"".join(['a', 'b', 'c', ' ', 'd', 'e']).replace(" ", "")`

Comment: In your output you are including the space and where does the 'f' come from?

Comment: What do you mean with "exclude the spaces"? The result that you show includes the space. An how do you join the list? Please [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps not the optimal, but an acceptable way is to first turn the `list` into a `string` with `string.join`, and then remove the spaces with `string.replace`.

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', ' ', 'd', 'e']
st = ''.join(lst) # list to string
no_space = st.replace(" ","") # replace space with nothing
```